# Understanding the use of any() and all() in numpy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, logic, conditional-statements

What's the difference between the following:

```
a = np.array([2,3,4])
b = np.array([2,7,8])

if a.any() == b.all():
   print('yes')
```

and

```
a = np.array([2,3,4])
b = np.array([2,7,8])

if a.any() == b.any():
   print('yes')
```

In both situations, `'yes'` is printed.

Comment: Those are meant more for boolean arrays. What's the intended operation?

Comment: For integers, only 0 counts as `False`.  Since your examples don't have any 0s, both `all` and `any` return `True`.

Comment: The thing to understand here might be that you are never actually comparing anything from `a` with anything in `b`. The two expressions, `a.any()` and `b.all()` are evaluated on their own (and as explained in the other comments, both evaluate to `True`), so what you end up checking is `True == True`, which is also `True`.

Comment: Thank you for your response. As a follow up, how would I check if at least one element in a is the same as b, and how would I check if ALL elements in a are the same as b (in the same sequence, therefore the same array). I suppose I could subtract them and then use any() and all()?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`any()` and `all()` are intended for boolean arrays. `any()` returns `True` if there's any values that are equal to `True` in the array. `all()` returns `True` if all values in the array are equal to `True`.
For integers/floats the functionality is similar, except that they return `True` if the value `0` is not found in the array.
In your example, since both `a.any()` and `a.all()` will return `True`, it follows that `a.any() == a.all()`.

Try executing the following code to see how it works in practice.

```
a = np.asarray([1,2,3])
b = np.asarray([-1,0,1])
c = np.asarray([True, False])

print(a.any())
print(a.all())

print(b.any())
print(b.all())

print(c.any())
print(c.all())
```

Comment: I did not realize any() and all() only referred to boolean arrays. Thank you for your response!

Answer (score 1):

On 1D numpy arrays of integers like yours, `any` will give you `True` if and only if *some* element is non-zero, whereas `all` will give you `True` if and only if *all* elements are non-zero.

So your first snippet of code translates into:
"Print yes if the answer to the question 'Is there some non-zero element in `a`?' is the same as the answer to 'Are all elements of `b` non-zero'?".

and the second into:
"Print yes if the answer to the question 'Is there some non-zero element in `a`?' is the same as the answer to 'Is there some non-zero element in `b`?'".

Answer (score 1):

I think the original post was due to a misunderstanding in combining logical operation (such as ==) and methods np.any() and np.all() when comparing 2 tables. Following the answer from @user2653663, I thought it is worth to complete it by the following example:

```py
    import numpy as np
    a = np.asarray([1,2,3])
    b = np.asarray([1,0,1])
    print((a == b).any())
    print((a == b).all())
    True
    False
```

The first print will return True as the compare operation "cell by cell" found at least 1 equal cell in both tables; which is in our case a[0] == b[0]. As the second returned False because not all cells are equals. You can easily visualize why by doing:

```
print(a == b)
[ True False False]
```