# numpy check all elements are False

Tags: python, numpy

I have a `numpy` 1-D array containing boolean values of `True` or `False`. I want to check whether all of them are `False` such that a single `True/False` is returned whether all elements in the `numpy` array are False or True

```
x = np.array([False, False, False])  # this should return True, since all values are False
y = np.array([True, True, True])  # this should return False, since all values are True
z = np.array([True, False, True]) # this should return False, since not all values are False
```

I looked into `np.all()`, but that does not see to solve my problem.

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check if all values in the columns of a numpy matrix are the same?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14859458/how-to-check-if-all-values-in-the-columns-of-a-numpy-matrix-are-the-same)

Comment: Boolean + `all()`: `(x==False).all()`

Comment: Did you check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50801454/understanding-the-use-of-any-and-all-in-numpy-arrays

Answer (score 9):

Compare each item with `False` and then reduce using `np.all`

```
np.all(x == False)
```

Comment: Maybe just `(~x).all()`?

Answer (score 4):

You can use Numpy's [`all()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.all.html):

> `numpy.all(a, axis=None, out=None, keepdims=<no value>)[source]`
>
> Test whether all array elements along a given axis evaluate to True.

```
for numpy_array in (x, y, z):
    print((~numpy_array).all())
```

And the output should be:

```
True
False
False
```